# Removing image links from a list

Tags: python, image, list

How would I go about removing image links (e.g. http://www.example.com/example.png) from a list of links? This includes .png, .jpg, and .gif file formats.

Comment: Your question suggests that you want us to write your code for you. Please provide additional motivation for us to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
regex = re.compile('\.jpg$|\.gif$|\.png$', re.IGNORECASE)
url_list = ['http://www.example.com/example.png', 'http://www.example.com/example']
urls_without_images = filter(lambda url: not regex.search(url), url_list)
```

Comment: I disagree that it's difficult on what's being asked.

Answer (score 1):

`list.remove('http://www.example.com/example.png')`

Comment: +1 for a humorous response to a poorly stated question. I have updated the question to read "e.g." instead of "i.e." ;)

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry for the poor question. I didn't mean to offend you ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're after something like this:

```
for idx in xrange(len(url_list) - 1, -1, -1):
    url = url_list[idx]
    ext = url.rpartition('.')[-1]
    if ext in ('png', 'gif', 'jpg'):
        del url_list[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

With the regexp (so with re module) is fairly simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for the extension with endswith:

```
for item in list:
  if (item.lower().endswith(".png") or item.lower().endswith(".gif") or item.lower().endswith(".jpg")):
    pass
  else:
    finallist.append(item)
```

Comment: -1 This is a bad idea because urls may have various encodings that would pass your `endswith` test but still refer to an image with that extension.

Comment: Good point, it would be better to use os.path.splitext and then remove ?extra or %extra endings.